# Confusion for the shape of ROC curve

Tags: python, dataset, shapes, curve, roc

When I use 100 data, the roc curve looks much like squares. But when the number of data increases, the **square shape fades**. Is it **normal for the ROC** curve to look like in picture b for many data. (for example:700 data)?

figure 1 is for fewer datasets and figure 2 is for large datasets. Can anyone tell me the reason behind **the difference between the two graphs**? is it only because of the **data number** or is there any **error for the second graph**?

[ROC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijFhW.jpg)

Comment: The resolution of the ROC curve is given by how many different combinations of TPR vs FPR you can have. This depends on different factors. Smaller datasets tend to have less combinations but is not the only factor. The resolution of your threshold will be another factor, giving more points to the ROC curve. Then the properties of your data will also affect this resolution (maybe your data only allows a limited number of combinations of TPR and FPR)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thank you for your reply. I was asked for a project to change my ROC curve because I was told the" ROC curve must be square". so based on your answer,is it okay to say that the ROC curve does not always have to be square shape? Because I have tried some times, but the square shape is fading when I used all the data of my dataset.

Comment: The step-like shape is not really "fading", it's just that the steps are becoming smaller and smaller as you add more data and so if you look from a distance the graph will look somewhat "smoother", but this is definitely to be expected.